# Multiplication in LC3 without knowing which registers are full

Tags: assembly, lc3

How would I write assembly code to multiply two registers if I don't know which registers are full?

I am writing a C program that expands a `mult` macro or pseudo-instruction in LC3 code to multiply two registers.  So I do not have access to the assembly code to know which are full.

But the `mult` "instruction" is specified to only write the destination, without modifying any other registers.  There's no general way to figure out which registers might be unused or ok to modify at a certain point in an asm file, so how can I use any temporaries for a loop?

For example:
Let's say this is the ASM file, input to my program.  The output would be another asm file, using a sequence of other instructions to replace the `mult`.

```
LD      R1, THREE
LD      R2, TWO

MULT R2, R3, R4  ; (This multiplies Register three and four and loads the result into R2).
```

*I am converting the MULT code into code LC3 knows and can execute*

If I do not have access to this original file, then I wouldn't know that Register 2 has something in it in order to not choose it as a counter when I am writing the code to multiply registers 2 and 3. The easiest way to multiply is to use a counter and then keep adding over and over.

**How would I multiply if I am unable to choose a register to use as a counter?**

I have tried using a counter, however this does not work without knowing which register is free.

Comment: Allocate stack space and stores your chosen registers in that space.  Perform the calculation using the saved registers.  Stash the result where it should go.  Restore the registers you saved (and deallocate the stack space?).

Comment: So you need to expand a `mult reg, reg,reg` pseudo-instruction, without destroying any other registers, not even the inputs.  As Jonathan says, save/restore a register on the stack around it.  But this is generally a bad design, forcing inefficient code even if the caller does have some spare registers.  Normally when you make a macro that needs a temporary register should ask the "caller" to provide one, as an extra arg.  Or specify this `mult` as destroying one or both of its inputs as well as writing the destination, and let the caller worry about it (and require all 3 regs unique)

Comment: (Destroying both inputs would allow a shift-and-add instead of just adding in a loop, O(log2 n) or fixed 16 iterations, instead of O(n).  e.g. `for(unsigned msk=1 ; msk != 0 ; msk<<=1, b<<=1) prod += (a&msk) ? b : 0;`.  Where left-shift is `msk+=msk`.  Oh right, since LC3 doesn't have right shift I had to left-shift a mask in a 3rd register instead of right-shifting `a`.

Comment: LC-3 doesn't necessarily have a stack set up (if it does it's R6), but since your multiply code is not recursive (right!?), you don't need a stack — just save the registers you need to some global variables near/after your code.  This is very common in LC-3, especially with R7 (the return address register, which is set/clobbered by a call and also by the I/O traps).

Comment: @PeterCordes, fyi, by my experience, little LC-3 coursework sets up a stack / stack-pointer, and the typical alternative for saving & restoring registers that should be (call-) preserved (on LC-3 without a stack) is to store them in global variables (and forgo recursion, reentrancy, multithreading, etc..).

Comment: @ErikEidt: And I guess forgo interrupt handling; using static storage for register-saving would create a problem if an interrupt handler used `mult` and the code being interrupted was in the middle of a `mult`.  So in terms of reentrancy considerations, that makes `mult` like a function using static vars.  Beginner LC-3 code doesn't normally do interrupts, but google found some stuff about LC-3 interrupt handling.  If you don't care about that, then yes, having this macro preprocessor reserve some static storage just for this mult macro would work.  (I'm hesitant to say pseudointruction now)